# Find app causing: Sending non-protected broadcast android.intent.action.SU_SESSION_CHANGED from system

Tags: adb, system-error, intents

I'm trying to find out what is responsible for constantly causing the following messages to be printed to logcat.

```
10-08 11:28:30.919  5258  5273 E ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast android.intent.action.SU_SESSION_CHANGED from system 5258:system/1000 pkg android
10-08 11:28:30.919  5258  5273 E ActivityManager: java.lang.Throwable
10-08 11:28:30.919  5258  5273 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:19162)
10-08 11:28:30.919  5258  5273 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:19767)
10-08 11:28:30.919  5258  5273 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:19909)
10-08 11:28:30.919  5258  5273 E ActivityManager:       at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcastAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1130)
10-08 11:28:30.919  5258  5273 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.AppOpsService$2.run(AppOpsService.java:142)
10-08 11:28:30.919  5258  5273 E ActivityManager:       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
10-08 11:28:30.919  5258  5273 E ActivityManager:       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 11:28:30.919  5258  5273 E ActivityManager:       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
10-08 11:28:30.919  5258  5273 E ActivityManager:       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
10-08 11:28:30.919  5258  5273 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

PID 5258 is "system_server".

How can I do this?

I'm running Lineage OS 15.1 / Android 8.1.

Comment: Try `adb shell dumpsys activity broadcasts`. You might be able to see the sender app.

Comment: same issues any help.

Comment: I have a similar issue, seeing this messaging come out.  I am using a Zebra scanner android device, the fact the scanner stops doing anything useful when I hit the scanner button until device reboot seems related to me getting this message to come out.  Sorry, that probably doesn't help your case, but in my case seems related to Zebra's drivers.